# How to output my input with answer in javaScript

Tags: javascript, html, input, output

I want to take 
one `var = input` 
and add for `eg: 5` to that input and then I would like to print my input into my html file.

> Eg: (I know about matching `getElementbyId`s, I just have trouble displaying my answer and appending.

```
  <script>
    funtion printmsg (){
    var a = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
    var b = a+5;
     return b;
        /*i would like to keep my p[rogram going and appending  the answers until i tell the program to stop.*/
        </script>
 <body>
        <input id="myinput">
        <button onclick="printmsg">print</button>
        <span id="display"></span>

    </body>
```

Comment: output on what some element or? just output only.. if output only try alert(b);

Comment: It might help to have the HTML you're using as well, the specific answer will depend on that in part.

Comment: i want to do it in my html not in a window i tried doing innerHTML=b;

Comment: you have an error in your code,
you misspelt `function` as `funtion`

Comment: Please view the console for errors.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to consider using the property `onkeyup`, essentially, every time you input a character to the input field (using the keyboard). the function you assign (`myFunc` in this case) will be invoked.

```js
function myFunc(elem) {
  console.log(elem.value);
  // use Number to parse number string to a number
  input = new Number(elem.value);
  output = input + 5;
  document.getElementById('out').value = output;
}
```

```html
<p>input</p>
<input id="in" type="text" onkeyup="myFunc(this)"></input>
<p>answer</p>
<input id="out" type="text"></input>
```

Comment: ive never use onkeyup what does it do?

Comment: It's an event, in this case, every time you press a key (on the keypord while you have the input selected) the function assigned will be invoked. You can read more about it here http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeyup.asp

Comment: i just did thank you.  i am really fresh to this we started script 3 days ago so i am still now familiar with all the functions and methods and keywords

Comment: Also, I forgot to remove the line "console.log(elem.value)". I put that line there for debugging. It prints whatever you input into chrome console.

Comment: so the word number converts my variable to an integer?

Comment: I am new to stackoverflow and this is the first question I answered. Mark it as solved if It was the answer you were looking for. Or ask more questions and I'd be happy to help.

Comment: similar to parseInt in java?

Comment: If you know how to start a chat, we can have a quick chat and i can answer your questions.

Comment: It is very similar to parseint. In this case you are creating a javascript number type. in java you'd create a Integer type or a Double type and so on.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add another input element to the page when the button is clicked, do something like this:

```
<body>
<div id="inputList">
<input type="text" id="myInput" />
</div>
</body>

<script>
var theDiv = document.getElementById('inputList');
var newInput = document.createElement('input');
var a = document.getElementById('myInput').value;
var b = Number(a) + 5;
newInput.value = String(b);
theDiv.appendChild(newInput);
</script>
```

(*edit*) I made another suggestion of code in a comment, but to my chagrin there's no formatting in comments, so it's a mess. So I'll put it up here.

`myInput` is the new input field that is created. If you would want that to be the new place for input to be taken the next time the button is pushed, then maybe you want:

```
<script>
var theDiv = document.getElementById('inputList');
var a = document.getElementById("myInput");
var printmsg = function() {
   var newInput = document.createElement('input');
   var b = Number(a.value) + 5;
   newInput.value = String(b);
   theDiv.appendChild(newInput);
   a = newInput;
};
</script>
```

Comment: how come you never refer to myInput that being where you actually input the information?

Comment: its a little more clear now how come you call the div inputlist and the actual input box?

Comment: I just created a div so that I'd have something to append the new input elements to.

Comment: so  now i want to take for example 10 and add 5 i want the program to display the result when i click a button and i want to enter a next number  but i want to see the result of my last input and i want to keep going until i type for example end im guessing i would have to add a button to your code and assign an oclick to a the function